# Run ffmpeg from batch locally

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I can’t run ffmpeg using batch file.

I created `run.bat` in the same folder as `ffmpeg.exe`. There is also “out” folder with images. I want to convert that images to mp4 file. In batch file I wrote

```
ffmpeg -framerate 50 -i out/%d.jpg render.mp4
```

I tried all combinations of brackets, “run” or another batch commands. Ffmpeg seems to open but immediately closes.

If to use just cmd, with cd command to locate folder, all works fine.

---

I need to run it without inputting absolute path to ffmpeg

Comment: You're using a batch file, therefore you need to double up the percent characters, `out\%%d.jpg` instead of `out/%d.jpg`!

Comment: 1. Your code is placed in a `for` loop, right? 2. The Windows path separator is `\ `but not `/`!

Comment: @aschipfl, no, ffmpeg do it automatically. Added to answer, thank You.

Answer (score 1):

As @Compo figured, I had to use `%%` as `%` character(like `\\` to use `\`), and You may find useful to add “pause” to batch file, so the correct command is:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 50 -i out/%%d.jpg render.mp4
pause
```

Also, you better use `\` instead of `/`

Comment: Pause makes no difference to your command at all. Please read my comment.

Comment: @Compo yeah I forgot about this, thank You. Edited my question

Comment: You'll also note from my comment, that I provided the correct Windows path separator. Regardless of the fact that Windows may autocorrect your invalid path, that shouldn't prevent you from using the correct one.